# I have a registerLazySingleton yet i gives Error: Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type FireStoreLinkRepository is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter, firebase, dependency-injection, flutter-dependencies

I made a separate function for initialising Dependencies and called it in main File.

There is no compile time error but when i run that specific part of code

It gives me

> Error: Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type FireStoreRepository
> is not registered inside GetIt.  (Did you accidentally do GetIt
> sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;

I have multiple registerLazySingleton does the sequence of them matter ?

So here is the main.dart file :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  initializeDependencies();
  Widget myApp = Phoenix(child: const MyApp());
  runApp(myApp);
}
```

this is the initialised Dependencies function :

```
final injector = GetIt.I;

Future<void> initializeDependencies() async {
  // shared prefs instance
  final sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  injector.registerLazySingleton<SharedPreferences>(() => sharedPrefs);

  // Repository

  injector.registerLazySingleton<FireStoreRepository>(
    () => FireStoreRepositoryImpl(),
  );
```